# Angular ngModel not set radio button value inside ngFor

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, radio-button

I am new on angular, need your assistance in one of my problem. I have a scenario where I am getting array of objects from API like

```
[{name: "abc", score: 2},{name: ""def, score: 3}]
```

here score is from 0 to 3. And I have to show the score on UI like below image
[image]

first radio button is for score 0 and second for score 1 till last i.e score 3

and my angular code is

```
<div *ngFor="let mark of marks; let ind = index">
    {{mark.name}}
    <input type="radio" [value]="0" name="score" id="zero"
                                                [(ngModel)]="mark.score">
    <input type="radio" [value]="1" name="score" id="one"
                                                [(ngModel)]="mark.score">
    <input type="radio" [value]="2" name="score" id="two"
                                                [(ngModel)]="mark.score">
    <input type="radio" [value]="3" name="score" id="three"
                                                [(ngModel)]="mark.score">

</div>
```

If I run the code, I am getting only last name score in list is checked with the score and rest of the above scores show blank.

P.S: And make edit score again with the new scores.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Having different name for each radio button will solve the problem.

```
<div *ngFor="let mark of marks; let i = index">
  {{mark.name}}
  <input type="radio" value="0" id="zero" [name]="marks[i].name + i" [(ngModel)]="marks[i].score">
  <input type="radio" value="1" id="one" [name]="marks[i].name + i" [(ngModel)]="marks[i].score">
  <input type="radio" value="2" id="two" [name]="marks[i].name + i" [(ngModel)]="marks[i].score">
  <input type="radio" value="3" id="three" [name]="marks[i].name + i" [(ngModel)]="marks[i].score">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Arun25...its show correct vales as coming from the api but when I change any score it makes all radio buttons with same value...

Answer (score 0):

This is because ngModel for each radio will be the one which is selected.
Try to bind new variable to ngModel..
Try this : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radio-button-api

Answer (score 0):

Good that you accepted answer; but to answer the question in title.

Set `value` to `index`, like:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itemList; let i = index">

  <input type="radio" name="picker"
         [value]="i"
         [(ngModel)]="item.isPicked">

</div>
```