# dynamically set ngModel on radio button within ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-material, radio-button, ngfor, ngmodel

I have an array which has the following

```
"extras": [
      {
        "model": "TAS",
        "title": "Title One",
        "desc": "The item description",
        "options": [
          {
            "title": "Title 1"
          },
          {
            "title": "Title 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "model": "DOC",
        "title": "Title Two",
        "desc": "The item description",
        "options": [
          {
            "title": "Title 2"
          },
          {
            "title": "Title 2"
          },
          {
            "title": "Title 3"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

and the following HTML:

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let e of extras;let i = index;">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
          {{ e.title }}
        </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-description>
        {{ e.desc }}
      </mat-panel-description>

      <mat-radio-group aria-labelledby="extra items group label">
        <div class="extra-item" *ngFor="let eo of e.options">
          <mat-radio-button value="{{ eo.title }}" selected color="primary">
            <h3> {{ eo.title }} </h3>
          </mat-radio-button>
        </div>
      </mat-radio-group>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
```

This creates 2 separate radio groups (1 for TAS and 1 for DOC).
I have tried adding an `ngModel` on the `mat-radio-group` but then this only allows one value from both groups.
I have also tried things like `[(ngModel)]="extras[i]"` but I am getting back errors with this.

What I would like to have is two different results coming back from the ngModel (one for each object), is this achievable?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `[(ngModel)]="extras[i].options[0].title"` ? consider using `[value]="eo.title"`.

Comment: I don't quite understand how this'll work. 

I still need to have a variable in TS file which will be the same as `[(ngModel)]`, so how can I display the value of the selected radios for each object?

Comment: Create a component with `mat-radio-group` and add an Input `selectedValue` and `options`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular ngModel not set radio button value inside ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62969845/angular-ngmodel-not-set-radio-button-value-inside-ngfor)